# write cloudwatch logs with 'component', 'error' and other fields

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

In the cdk I can define these filters for the logs:

```
const pattern = logs.FilterPattern.all(
  logs.FilterPattern.stringValue('$.component', '=', 'HttpServer'),
  logs.FilterPattern.any(
    logs.FilterPattern.booleanValue('$.error', true),
    logs.FilterPattern.numberValue('$.latency', '>', 1000),
  ),
);
```

(From the docs).
But I don't know how to write logs that have these fields from my lambda function...